# kamailio v5.2 make error "ln: failed to create symbolic link 'libkamailio_ims.so.0': File exists"

Tags: kamailio

Tried to upgrade a server running version 5.1.4 to 5.2 , encounred following error which blocks make install

```sh
    ln: failed to create symbolic link 'libkamailio_ims.so.0': File exists
    ../../Makefile.libs:107: recipe for target 'libkamailio_ims.so.0' failed
    make[3]: [libkamailio_ims.so.0] Error 1 (ignored)
    ln: failed to create symbolic link 'libkamailio_ims.so': File exists
    ../../Makefile.libs:113: recipe for target 'libkamailio_ims.so' failed
    make[3]: [libkamailio_ims.so] Error 1 (ignored)
    LD (gcc) [L libkamailio_ims.so.0.1]     libkamailio_ims.so.0.1
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxml2
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    ../../Makefile.rules:191: recipe for target 'libkamailio_ims.so.0.1' failed
    make[3]: *** [libkamailio_ims.so.0.1] Error 1
    ../../Makefile.rules:157: recipe for target '../../lib/ims/libkamailio_ims.so' failed
    make[2]: *** [../../lib/ims/libkamailio_ims.so] Error 2
    Makefile:511: recipe for target 'modules' failed
    make[1]: *** [modules] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/kamailio_source_code/src'
    Makefile:27: recipe for target 'modules' failed
    make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

further clarifying this belong to IMS ICSCF module of kamailio and I have tried skipping all ims related modules while **make** both through modules list and command line make but to no avail. Maybe missing something here? Same

modules.lst

```
# the list of sub-directories with modules
modules_dirs:=modules

# the list of module groups to compile
cfg_group_include=

# the list of extra modules to compile
include_modules= db_mysql app_lua uuid topos topos_redis ndb_redis

# the list of static modules
static_modules=

# the list of modules to skip from compile list
skip_modules=ims_auth ims_charging ims_dialog ims_diameter_server ims_icscf ims_isc ims_ocs ims_qos ims_registrar_pcscf ims_registrar_scscf ims_usrloc_pcscf ims_usrloc_scscf

# the list of modules to exclude from compile list
exclude_modules= acc_radius app_java app_mono app_perl app_python auth_ephemeral auth_identity auth_radius carrierroute cdp cdp_avp cnxcc cplc crypto db2_ldap db_berkeley db_cassandra db_mongodb db_oracle db_perlvdb db_postgres db_sqlite db_unixodbc dialplan dnssec erlang evapi geoip geoip2 gzcompress h350 http_async_client http_client jansson janssonrpcc json jsonrpcc kazoo lcr ldap log_systemd memcached misc_radius ndb_cassandra ndb_mongodb  nsq osp outbound peering phonenum presence presence_conference presence_dialoginfo presence_mwi presence_profile presence_reginfo presence_xml pua pua_bla pua_dialoginfo pua_reginfo pua_rpc pua_usrloc pua_xmpp rabbitmq regex rls sctp snmpstats tls utils websocket xcap_client xcap_server xhttp_pi xmlops xmlrpc xmpp $(skip_modules) $(skip_modules)

modules_all= $(filter-out modules/CVS,$(wildcard modules/*))
modules_noinc= $(filter-out $(addprefix modules/, $(exclude_modules) $(static_modules)), $(modules_all)) 
modules= $(filter-out $(modules_noinc), $(addprefix modules/, $(include_modules) )) $(modules_noinc) 
modules_configured:=1
```

command line

```sh
    make skip_modules="*ims*" modules
```

Answer (score 0):

had to reset the config file by `make cfg`, it's ok now